# Button shine/glow with CSS3

Tags: css

I have a navigation menu that I'm trying to recreate using only CSS3 and HTML.  The design calls for a shine/glow on the currently selected menu button as per the "home" button on the attached pic.   Is that effect possible using just code or will I need to use the glow image?!
[image]

Notice the shine and white line is most visible towards the center of the button and then fades towards the edges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS3's [radial gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-radial-gradient) let you achieve a similar effect, although using a CSS background image may be easier for pixel-perfect adjustments. Specifically, CSS3's gradients are linear, even the radial ones.

I've constructed a small example using Firefox's radial gradients (support for Webkit will require quite different code): http://jsfiddle.net/rxMf6/

[image: Example of button with radial gradient]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="highlighted-button">
    <div class="highlight"></div>
    Button
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.highlighted-button {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    font: bold 0.8em Arial, sans-serif;
    padding-bottom: 0.9em;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 8em;
}

.highlight {
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center top, ellipse farthest-side,
                                     #fff 0%, #000 100%);
    height: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.4em;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this.  I was able to recreate the look using your code with a few tweaks.  Seems like the way to go.

Comment: yea, and it only works on a small percentage of browsers!! Consider this: use an image and it works in every browser or use just code and most people will think the menu looks old-school. See my solution below and compare.

Answer (score 1):

yes,that's shine is possible in css3.You adjust gradient as per your requirement.you us filter for IE.
i hope this example help's you.

```
.menu {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
    background: #000;
    width: 700px;
}
.menu ul {
    margin: 15px 0 15px 5px;
}
.menu ul li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: arial;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.menu ul li:before {
    display: inline;
    content: "/";
}
.menu ul li:first-child:before {
    content: " ";
    height:45px;
}
.menu ul li a {
    margin: 0 15px 0 15px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding:17px 30px 16px 30px;;
}
.menu ul li a:hover {
    border-top:1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #fff;
    padding:17px 30px 16px 30px;
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center -5px 45deg, ellipse farthest-corner, rgb(255, 255, 255)0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)70%) repeat #000;
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 0, 0, 50% 0,50, from(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)), to(#000));

}



    <nav>
                <div class="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">WHAT IS THIS?</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SWEAR DICTIONARY</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: thanks @sandeep.  Not quite the effect I was after. But close.  The answer from @ide above was the closest to what I was after.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You will need an image. There is really no way to achieve this effect with just code. Though most browsers can be handled with the use of CSS3 `box-shadow` or gradients, Internet Explorer 8, and partially IE 9 will have issues. To give proper cross-browsers support, you will have to use images to achieve the desired effect.

The reason I say you will need an image is very well may have to include additional markup and  hacky workarounds to achieve the effect. This is not desirable and could cause conflicts in trying to implement the CSS3 version as well.

Comment: css3 gradients could probably do it.

Comment: You'd need to do some minor CSS3 martial arts, but it seems very possible. CSS3 is capable of oblong gradients and absolutely positioning radial gradient centers. All that would be necessary here would be to layer on a separate element to take care of the radial gradient (since the linear gradient at the top of the button appears to persist). But yes, you *need* in image in the sense that it's not worth the headache trying to code and have browsers render this gradient.

Comment: @All Well you would not get the look across all browsers. I do not see why you should give some users a nice look while giving others the shaft. Currently only two browsers support CSS3 gradients and they don't even use the CSS3 spec.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to explain your concern is regards to browser support?

Comment: @ghayes I've expanded upon my initial statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar CSS3 gradient. You can change the colors and get your desired look. I don't know if it is exactly like what you wanted though. It doesn't do a rounded look just a straight gradient.

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
linear,
left bottom,
left top,
color-stop(0.32, rgb(14,15,14)),
color-stop(0.7, rgb(0,0,0)),
color-stop(0.85, rgb(201,201,201))
);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
center bottom,
rgb(14,15,14) 32%,
rgb(0,0,0) 70%,
rgb(201,201,201) 85%
);
```

Comment: This will only work in Firefox and Webkit browsers (Chrome and Safari), though.

Comment: oh i guess your right...I guess images is the only way...Or maybe there is a way to do nested divs colored...like what google did...here http://stopdesign.com/archive/2009/02/04/recreating-the-button.html